# Java - BufferedReader not reading from url

Tags: java, url, bufferedreader

I am trying to read from 45 pages that are all the same (except for the part im reading of course) and write them in a list of line lists.

I wrote this code so far:

```
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> linesWeNeed(){
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> returnListList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    for(int i = 1; i<=45; i++){
        int pageNum=(i*20)-20;
        System.out.println("PageNum"+pageNum);
        URL url=null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://tq.mot.gov.il/index.php?option=com_moofaq&iotype=w&view=category&lang_ovrrde=ENG&id=3&Itemid=29&limitstart="+pageNum);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("Oh uh!");
        }

        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("FATAL ERROR");

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArrayList<String> lineCodes = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> linesWeNeed = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;
        try {
            readLines:
            while((line=in.readLine())!=null){
                if(line.contains("</tr></table></div></div></li></ul></div></div><br /></div>")){
                    break readLines;
                }
                lineCodes.add(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(int o = 1; o>=lineCodes.size(); o++){
            String readLine = lineCodes.get(o-1);
            if(o>=297){
                linesWeNeed.add(readLine);
            }

        }
        returnListList.add(linesWeNeed);
    }
    return returnListList;
}
```

There are no errors, but for some reason every list in the arraylist the methods return is empty. Why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int o = 1; o>=lineCodes.size(); o++){
```

Your loop condition is back to front. Try <=.

Answer (score 1):

> for(int o = 1; o>=lineCodes.size(); o++){

Double-check the loop condition there; seems like that block is never going to execute...